# Query XML column - get value based on other value in the same row

Tags: sql-server, xml

in my database I have an XML-column that looks like this:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <Einheit>Stck</Einheit>
    <Faktor>1</Faktor>
    <VkPreisEinheit>1</VkPreisEinheit>
    <VkMengenEinheit>1</VkMengenEinheit>
    <EkMengenEinheit>1</EkMengenEinheit>
    <StcklEinheit>1</StcklEinheit>
    <StcklDefinition>1</StcklDefinition>
    <KonsumentenEinheit>1</KonsumentenEinheit>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Einheit>Stück</Einheit>
    <Faktor>100</Faktor>
    <EinheitFaktor>Stck</EinheitFaktor>
    <EkPreisEinheit>1</EkPreisEinheit>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

What I want to achieve ist that I get the value from 'Faktor' only from the row where 'EkPreisEinheit' is 1

I have tried something with:

```
CASE WHEN isnull(convert(xml,xmlcolumn).value('(/Root/Row/EkPreisEinheit)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') = '1'     
     THEN isnull(convert(xml,xmlcolumn).value('(/Root/Row/Faktor)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     WHEN isnull(convert(xml,xmlcolumn).value('(/Root/Row/EkPreisEinheit)[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'') = '1'
     THEN isnull(convert(xml,xmlcolumn).value('(/Root/Row/Faktor)[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     ELSE ''  
     END AS Faktor
```

which would work if EKPreiseinheit would be found in both columns, but it only is in one. Also it could be that it is in the first row, or in the third if there was any. Is there any way to tackle this?

Comment: Is `xmlcolumn` not already the `xml` data type? If it is, why are you converting it? If not, why are you not using the correct data type?

Comment: The data in that column is just text, so I converting it into XML. I don't know much about XML, I dont even know if it is valid XML, it comes out of the system like this. So any help would be great...

Comment: If it isn't valid XML, then you can't parse it using SQL's inbuilt functions. Personally, I would firstly ensure that that you are using the correct datatype (`xml`) and ensure the data you are receiving is value. When you say "text" do you mean it's the `text` datatype? That's been deprecated for 15 years; you should reaklly not be using it anymore.

Comment: Yes the data type of the column is text. I can't do anything about it because, as I said, it ist build in the system and I can't change the data type here. I never had any issues converting it so I guess it is valid code. So again, is there a way to query only the one row where <EkPreisEinheit>1</EkPreisEinheit> can be found?

Comment: Right now I am fiddling around with left, right, charindex and reverse functions in SQL. It i s working but I guuess there must be a better way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for you. Few points to mention. (0) It handles XML directly from the table. (1) It converts XML data into XML data type via `TRY_CAST()`. So it will emit NULL when XML is not well-formed without generating any error. (2) It checks via `XPath` predicate for the `<Row>` element where 'EkPreisEinheit' element value is 1, and filters out anything else.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xmlcolumn NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES (N'<Root>
    <Row>
        <Einheit>Stck</Einheit>
        <Faktor>1</Faktor>
        <VkPreisEinheit>1</VkPreisEinheit>
        <VkMengenEinheit>1</VkMengenEinheit>
        <EkMengenEinheit>1</EkMengenEinheit>
        <StcklEinheit>1</StcklEinheit>
        <StcklDefinition>1</StcklDefinition>
        <KonsumentenEinheit>1</KonsumentenEinheit>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Einheit>Stück</Einheit>
        <Faktor>100</Faktor>
        <EinheitFaktor>Stck</EinheitFaktor>
        <EkPreisEinheit>1</EkPreisEinheit>
    </Row>
</Root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmlcolumn AS XML) AS xml_data
   from @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , col.value('(Faktor/text())[1]','INT') AS Faktor
    , col.value('(EkPreisEinheit/text())[1]','INT') AS EkPreisEinheit
FROM rs as tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xml_data.nodes('/Root/Row[EkPreisEinheit="1"]') AS tab(col);
```

> Output

```
+----+--------+----------------+
| ID | Faktor | EkPreisEinheit |
+----+--------+----------------+
|  1 |    100 |              1 |
+----+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys, this on works like a charm. Exactly what I was looking for. I just made some adjustments to run it directly from the table and I changed 'INT' to float because the factor could be decimal.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with multiple of the same node, you want to use `nodes` in the `FROM` to create a row for each one. This means you end up with something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<Root>
  <Row>
    <Einheit>Stck</Einheit>
    <Faktor>1</Faktor>
    <VkPreisEinheit>1</VkPreisEinheit>
    <VkMengenEinheit>1</VkMengenEinheit>
    <EkMengenEinheit>1</EkMengenEinheit>
    <StcklEinheit>1</StcklEinheit>
    <StcklDefinition>1</StcklDefinition>
    <KonsumentenEinheit>1</KonsumentenEinheit>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Einheit>Stück</Einheit>
    <Faktor>100</Faktor>
    <EinheitFaktor>Stck</EinheitFaktor>
    <EkPreisEinheit>1</EkPreisEinheit>
  </Row>
</Root>';

WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.YourXML
    FROM (VALUES(@XML)) V(YourXML))
SELECT R.R.value('(EkPreisEinheit/text())[1]','int') AS EkPreisEinheit
FROM YourTable YT
     --Due to the misuse of datatypes you'll need a CONVERT in a VALUES clause here instead
     CROSS APPLY YT.YourXML.nodes('/Root/Row') R(R)
WHERE R.R.value('(EkPreisEinheit/text())[1]','int') IS NOT NULL;
```